# Efficient way to perform a triangular sum with .sum over a matrix F(a[i], a[j]), given the vector a

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `a` and need to perform a summation over two indices, something as

```
for i in (range, n): 
    for j in (i+1, n):
        F(a[i] - a[j])
```

where `F` is a function: the sum is reminding of summing over the upper triangle of an array.

I read the interesting thread on [Fastest way in numpy to sum over upper triangular elements with the least memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629601/fastest-way-in-numpy-to-sum-over-upper-triangular-elements-with-the-least-memory) and did my trials: indeed ARRAY.sum is a very fast way to sum over the elements of an upper triangular matrix.

To apply the method to my case, I first need to define an array such as

```
A[i,j] = F(a[i],a[j])
```

and then compute

```
(A.sum() - np.diag(A).sum())/2
```

I could define the array `A` via two for loops of course, but I wondering if there is a faster, numpy way.

In another case, the function `F` was simply equal to

```
F = a[i]*a[j]
```

and I could write

```
def sum_upper_triangular(vector):
    A = np.tensordot(vector,vector,0)
    return (A.sum() - np.diag(A).sum())/2
```

which is incredibly faster than summing directly with `sum()`, or nested for loops.

If `F` is more articulated, for example

```
np.exp(a[i] - a[j])
```

I would like to know what the most efficient way.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you share the actual `F` that you are working with?

Comment: @Divakar, F = a[i]*a[j] * G( a[i]-a[j]), where G  is the Mittag Leffler function taking as argument a[i] - a[j]. I guess already knowing how to deal with the example function I described in the post would be useful to me. As a matter of fact, I would already not be sure how to best deal with F = a[i] - a[j]. Thanks a lot

Comment: This problem depends on the function G. It is very easy to implement a Cython or Numba solution for the summation problem. But to geed a good speedup you have to implement the function G also as a Cython cdef or with Numba or wrap a C implementation

Comment: I appreciate the specific function G will affect the choice of the optimal approach. As i mentioned, I would already be content to learn how to handle the example i mention, np.exp(a[i] - a[j]),  without using sum()

Comment: Not certain about this, but it may help to store a[i] so you don't have to re-retrieve that value

Comment: Also, in your original ecample, it seems there's only 4 combinations you're checking (range, range+1), (n, n+1), (range, n), (n,n), is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `scipy.spatial.pdist` and set whatever function you wanted to the metric.  As a bonus, `pdist` only computes the off-diagonal triangle, so you don't need to remove it from your `sum`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def sum_upper_tri(arr, F = lambda x, y: x*y):
    return pdist(arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], -1), metric = F).sum()/2
```

If you want something super fast though, you're going to need `numba`:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def sum_upper_tri_jit(arr, F = lambda x, y: x * y):
    out = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            out += F(arr[i], arr[j])
    return out / 2
```

Haven't quite figured a way to `@njit` that yet, but if i can it'll be much faster.

In any case, a specially-built function each expected `F` will be much faster.  For example, the `exp(|x-y|)` case (reminder that `exp(x-y)` is not symmetric: x-y != y-x)

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def sum_upper_tri_exp(arr):
    out = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            out += np.exp(np.abs(arr[i] - arr[j]))
    return out / 2
```

This is about 100x faster than the above

if you don't want the summation, you can use:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def sum_upper_tri_exp(arr):
    out = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            out += [np.exp(arr[i] - arr[j])]
    return out
```

Comment: You can jit the F function before calling it in the sum_upper_tri_exp function, or use a closure eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59256512/4045774 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58752553/4045774

Comment: You're welcome to make an answer for the bounty @max9111, if I tried I'd just be cribbing your answers there.

Comment: @-Daniel, thanks for your input. I have regretfully been unable to log over the past 3 days, I hope the bounty points have been awarded. That not being the case, please suggest if I have a way to accept your reply. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly you want to do the following:

```
result = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(n-1): 
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        result.append(F(a[i] - a[j]))
```

for some function `F`. Also, the operation between matrix elements can be any other (e.g. multiplication `*`). Below is one way to do it without the for-loops:

```
iu = np.triu_indices(n, k=1)
A_j, A_i = np.meshgrid(a, a)
res = F(A_i[iu] - A_j[iu])  # e.g. F = np.exp
```

Explanation (for `n=5`):

```
A_i = [[a[0], a[0], a[0], a[0], a[0],
       [a[1], a[1], a[1], a[1], a[1],
       [a[2], a[2], a[2], a[2], a[2],
       [a[3], a[3], a[3], a[3], a[3],
       [a[4], a[4], a[4], a[4], a[4]]

A_j = [[a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4],
       [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4],
       [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4],
       [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4],
       [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]]

A_i[iu] = [a[0], a[0], a[0], a[0], a[1], a[1], a[1], a[2], a[2], a[3]]
A_j[iu] = [a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[3], a[4], a[4]]
```

Then perform element-wise computations and apply element-wise F:

```
F(A_i[iu] - A_j[iu]) = [ 
    F(a[0] - a[1]), F(a[0] - a[2]), F(a[0] - a[3]), F(a[0] - a[4]),
    F(a[1] - a[2]), F(a[1] - a[3]), F(a[1] - a[4]),
    F(a[2] - a[3]), F(a[2] - a[4]),
    F(a[3] - a[4])]
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I did accept the other question simply because the method therein suggested turned out to be faster. Thanks again